# Exclude Japanese Stopwords from File

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words, mecab

I am trying to remove *Japanese* stopwords from a text corpus from twitter.
Unfortunately the frequently used nltk does not contain Japanese, so I had to figure out a different way.

This is my MWE:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import MeCab
import re

# slothlib
slothlib_path = "http://svn.sourceforge.jp/svnroot/slothlib/CSharp/Version1/SlothLib/NLP/Filter/StopWord/word/Japanese.txt"
sloth_file = urllib.request.urlopen(slothlib_path)

# stopwordsiso
iso_path = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-ja/master/stopwords-ja.txt"
iso_file = urllib.request.urlopen(iso_path)
stopwords = [line.decode("utf-8").strip() for line in iso_file]

stopwords = [ss for ss in stopwords if not ss==u'']
stopwords = list(set(stopwords))

text = '日本語の自然言語処理は本当にしんどい、と彼は十回言った。'
tagger = MeCab.Tagger("-Owakati")
tok_text = tagger.parse(text)

ws = re.compile(" ")
words = [word for word in ws.split(tok_text)]
if words[-1] == u"\n":
    words = words[:-1]
ws = [w for w in words if w not in stopwords]

print(words)
print(ws)
```

**Successfully Completed**: It does give out the original tokenized text as well as the one without stopwords

```
['日本語', 'の', '自然', '言語', '処理', 'は', '本当に', 'しんどい', '、', 'と', '彼', 'は', '十', '回', '言っ', 'た', '。']
['日本語', '自然', '言語', '処理', '本当に', 'しんどい', '、', '十', '回', '言っ', '。']
```

---

There is still 2  issues I am facing though:

**a) Is it possible to have 2 stopword lists regarded?** namely `iso_file` and `sloth_file` ? so if the word is either a stopword from `iso_file` or `sloth_file` it will be removed? (I tried to use line 14 as
`stopwords = [line.decode("utf-8").strip() for line in zip('iso_file','sloth_file')]`
but received an error as tuple attributes may not be decoded

**b) The ultimate goal would be to generate a new text file in which all stopwords are removed**.

I had created this MWE

```
### first clean twitter csv
import pandas as pd
import re
import emoji

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

def cleaner(tweet):
    tweet = re.sub(r"@[^\s]+","",tweet) #Remove @username 
    tweet = re.sub(r"(?:\@|http?\://|https?\://|www)\S+|\\n","", tweet) #Remove http links & \n
    tweet = " ".join(tweet.split())
    tweet = ''.join(c for c in tweet if c not in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI) #Remove Emojis
    tweet = tweet.replace("#", "").replace("_", " ") #Remove hashtag sign but keep the text
    return tweet
df['text'] = df['text'].map(lambda x: cleaner(x))
df['text'].to_csv(r'cleaned.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')

### remove stopwords

import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import MeCab
import re

# slothlib
slothlib_path = "http://svn.sourceforge.jp/svnroot/slothlib/CSharp/Version1/SlothLib/NLP/Filter/StopWord/word/Japanese.txt"
sloth_file = urllib.request.urlopen(slothlib_path)

#stopwordsiso
iso_path = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-ja/master/stopwords-ja.txt"
iso_file = urllib.request.urlopen(iso_path)
stopwords = [line.decode("utf-8").strip() for line in iso_file]

stopwords = [ss for ss in stopwords if not ss==u'']
stopwords = list(set(stopwords))

with open("cleaned.txt",encoding='utf8') as f:
    cleanedlist = f.readlines()
    cleanedlist = list(set(cleanedlist))

tagger = MeCab.Tagger("-Owakati")
tok_text = tagger.parse(cleanedlist)

ws = re.compile(" ")
words = [word for word in ws.split(tok_text)]
if words[-1] == u"\n":
    words = words[:-1]
ws = [w for w in words if w not in stopwords]

print(words)
print(ws)
```

While it works for the simple input text in the first MWE, for the MWE I just stated I get the error

```
in method 'Tagger_parse', argument 2 of type 'char const *'
Additional information:
Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'Tagger_parse'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    MeCab::Tagger::parse(MeCab::Lattice *) const
    MeCab::Tagger::parse(char const *)
```

for this line: `tok_text = tagger.parse(cleanedlist)`
So I assume I will need to make amendments to the `cleanedlist`?

I have uploaded the cleaned.txt on github for reproducing the issue:
[txt on github][1]

Also: How would I be able to get the tokenized list that excludes stopwords back to a text format like cleaned.txt? Would it be possible to for this purpose create a df of ws?
Or might there even be a more simple way?

Sorry for the long request, I tried a lot and tried to make it as easy as possible to understand what I'm driving at :-)

Thank you very much!
[1]: https://gist.github.com/yin-ori/1756f6236944e458fdbc4a4aa8f85a2c

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to:

1. combine two lists of stopwords
2. save text that has had stopwords removed

For problem 1, if you have two lists you can make them into one list with `full_list = list1 + list2`. You can then make them into a `set` after that.

The reason you are getting the MeCab error is probably that you are passing a list to `parse`, which expects a string. (What MeCab wrapper are you using? I have never seen that particular error.) As a note, you should pass each individual tweet to MeCab, instead of the combined text of all tweets, something like:

```
tokenized = [tagger.parse(tweet) for tweet in cleanedlist]
```

That should resolve your problem.

Saving text with stopwords removed is just the same as any text file.

---

As a separate point...

Stopword lists are not very useful in Japanese because if you're using something like MeCab you already have part of speech information. So you should use that instead to throw out verb endings, function words, and so on.

Also removing stopwords is probably actively unhelpful if you're using any modern NLP methods, see the [spaCy preprocessing FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10243).

Comment: I see, thank you for the reply! :-) I was trying to prepare a textfile for AntConc - unfortunately if I do not exclude stopwords, when checking on word frequency for example, it will give out all kinds of non words like particles (even if part of speech info is contained). Therefore I was looking for a way to make that managable.

Comment: The point is that instead of using some list of random stopwords, you should filter words using the part of speech information provided by MeCab.

Comment: oh got that thank you! :-) but if I filter words through MeCab (excluding part of speech info?)  I would still need a filtered new text output right?

Comment: Yes, you still need the output. The idea is that instead of something like `if word in STOPWORDS` you do `if word.pos in ("助詞", ...)` to filter.